# Using Clisp on Git Bash

Tags: git, powershell, common-lisp, git-bash

This is just a quick question, but how do you run a "clisp" command in Git Bash.  It works in Windows Powershell, but not in Git Bash.
(The "clisp" command being for Common Lisp.)

This is all I am writing to both consoles:

```
clisp file.lisp
```

Is there a way to fix this?

*P.S. I know this seems like a stupid question, but I prefer Git Bash to Powershell (as I use git a lot), so I would like to have it working in Git Bash and if a problem similar arises again, I would desire to be able to resolve it.  Thanks.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Common Lisp,check if you have access to a Windows 10 with [WSL installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide).

That way, you can follow the [Common Lisp "Getting started" page](http://lisp-lang.org/learn/getting-started/) and install:

```
sudo apt-get install sbcl
```

That will be more compatible and complete than on a `git bash`.